Recover value function from its dual
I take as my reference Optimal Investment by Rogers (2013). Denote the agent's value function, which is convex, by $V(w)$, where $w$ is the state variable. Define the dual variable $z = V_w$, where the subscript denotes differentiation. Also define the dual value function
$$
 J(z) = V(w) - w z\ .
$$
I have two questions. Firstly, Rogers claims that the following identities hold:
$$
 J_z = -w\ , \quad J_{zz} = -1/V_{ww}\ .
$$
The first identity is clear enough, but how does one derive the second?
Secondly, Rogers demonstrates how this function is helpful in transforming the non-linear HJB equation for $V$ into a linear differential equation for $J$. Fair enough. What I don't understand is how to recover the original value function once we have solved for $J(z)$. If I substitute the available information into the above equation I end up with the differential equation
$$
 J(V_w) = V - w V_w\ ,
$$
which Mathematica says can be solved as
$$
 V(w) = C w + J(C)\ ,
$$
where $C$ is a constant of integration. But $V$ will not in general be a linear function: where I am going wrong? Or more precisely, how can $V$ be recovered from $J$?

Draft attempt..
$$ d_z J = d_z V - w - z d_z w  $$
where
$$ d_z V = \partial_z V + \partial_w V d_z w$$
noting $\partial_z V = 0$ and $\partial_w V \equiv z$
$$ \implies d_z V = z d_z w $$
and
$$ \implies d_z J = -w $$
Now,
$$ d^2_{zz} J = - d_z w$$
If,
$$ d_z w = \frac{1}{d_w z} = \frac{1}{d^2_{ww} V }$$
then,
$$ d^2_{zz} J = \frac{-1}{d^2_{ww} V} $$
